# Unemployment Insurance

Tags: taxes, llc, insurance

What is the best source of information about financial and legal requirements for LLCs?  My husband has been paying my quarterly taxes, but I want to make sure we aren't missing anything without investing in a professional accountant or lawyer.  Is there an easy-to-navigate site with all the information I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't, go to an accountant.

Go to an affordable one, or go on a one-time consult or whatever option you have to save money on this but you really do need professional advice. If you get this wrong, it will cost you a lot more.